# Errno::EACCES: Permission denied when installing gems via gitlab

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler, gitlab

I'm trying to setup gitlab and thus install some gems from another user account using sudo,
but I'm constantly getting `Permission denied` error.

```
sudo -u gitlab -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres

> Using ... ( a lot of successful gems there )
> Using pygments.rb (0.3.2) from https://github.com/gitlabhq/pygments.rb.git (at master) 
> Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - pygments.rb-0.3.2.gem
> An error occurred while installing pygments.rb (0.3.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
> Make sure that `gem install pygments.rb -v '0.3.2'` succeeds before bundling.\



sudo -u gitlab -H gem install pygments.rb -v '0.3.2'

> Successfully installed pygments.rb-0.3.2
> 1 gem installed
> Installing ri documentation for pygments.rb-0.3.2...
> Installing RDoc documentation for pygments.rb-0.3.2...
# no matter how many times I run this command, I always get the same output
# as if the gem installation doesn't stick 


# I've tried to chmod
chmod 777 -R /usr/local/lib/ruby



# then Again
sudo -u gitlab -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres
# same result, Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - pygments.rb-0.3.2.gem
```

Comment: Have you tried just `su - gitlab` to login as that user and then run the commands and when you're finished logout? It might be easier.

Comment: Yep. I did. Same result (`Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - pygments.rb-0.3.2.gem`)

Comment: You could try to use project local dirs for the bin and gem dirs. I do it on all my projects now e.g. `cd /home/gitlab/gitlab` then `bundle install --binstubs --path vendor` (as gitlab) and all the gems go in ./vendor and all the exe's in ./bin, relative to the project root.

Comment: Well, it worked with installing into `vendor` sub directory. Therefore I guess the initial problem was with permissions on the current directory

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lain suggested to try to install the bundles into another sub directory. When that worked out, it became clear the problem was about permissions in the current directory.

Executing `chown -R gitlab:gitlab .` has solved the problem.

In the gitlab installation guide there is a `gem install` command preceding our story that was ran as root and probably the `gemfile` or some other file had permissions change during that.

Comment: Never change all permissions or owners in all directories and subdirectories unless you really know what does the change.

Answer (score 10):

This is a permissions bug in ruby-2.0.0-p195 rvm with bundle install

are you using rvm? did you try chmod with sudo?

`chmod 755 (or 777) ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/build_info/`

Answer (score 2):

I did the following and got things working.

I changed the permission for the Gemfile. i.e. `chmod 755 Gemfile`

Then I did a `sudo bundle install`. This got things working and all the gems got installed. I could then start my app by `rails server`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `Gemfile.lock` is owned by the user running the command

Answer (score 0):

Although Alex's answer is correct,this worked for me as well

```
sudo chown -R git:git /path/to/external/volume
```

I'm using Digital Ocean's Gitlab Image